# Javascript style display='none' to 'block' not working on iPhone Chrome/Safari

Tags: javascript, css

**My goal**: click on div to show/hide another div.
All works well on pc browsers

**Problem**: Not working on iPhone in some odd reason.
Show/hide div:

```
<div class="portoTextDetails">
   <p>
     text....</a>
   </p>
</div>
```

Clickable div:

```
<div class="readPortoTextDetails"></div>
```

Javascript to handle the click listener and show/dhide functsions:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var portoTextDetailsOpen = false;
  var portoItems = document.getElementsByClassName("portoTextDetails");
  var i;
  $(".readPortoTextDetails").click(function() {
    if(portoTextDetailsOpen){
        for (i = 0; i < portoItems.length; i++) {
            portoItems[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
        portoTextDetailsOpen = false;
    }else{
        for (i = 0; i < portoItems.length; i++) {
            portoItems[i].style.display = 'block';
        }
        portoTextDetailsOpen = true;
    }
  })
});
```

I have managed to confirm that the problem is in the style.display = 'block'/'none' part of the code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It's funny that you use jQuery yet use vanilla JS for something jQuery could have done so easily:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".readPortoTextDetails").click(function() {
    $(".portoTextDetails").toggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: I used vanilla cause what I am really doing after I get this simple thing to work is change the height of a div with transitions. Don't know if jQuery will do it or not but I know how it works in vanilla and it is a simple build. My question is more directed at why wont js style changes work in iPhone?